# Google doc API - try to create a table with text

Tags: c#, google-docs-api

I succeeded to add a table to my google doc by using the API, but I cannot add text in the correct cells. does anybody has a successful sample for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide a sample of what you tried so far

Comment: I found this sample in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876436/how-to-add-content-to-google-doc-table-cell-in-c-sharp  but got stuck in the same place he did

Comment: Have you tried reversing the loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add content to google doc table cell in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876436/how-to-add-content-to-google-doc-table-cell-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Hi, yes I did.  It works. if somebody needs my sample code I'll be happy to help. Thanks guys.