# google docs api insertText multiple table cells

Tags: google-docs-api

Using how does one update multiple table cells in a single request ?
Is it possible to specify the location of the cell by row and cell range instead of startIndex ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add content to table cell via google-docs-api request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56735529/how-to-add-content-to-table-cell-via-google-docs-api-request)

Comment: And also, does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56876436/7108653

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/q/56876436/7108653  would do it, the trick is to reverse the requests array because the startIndex will shift after the first request is processed